# How to implement Angular 2 fullpage.js scrolloverflow

Tags: html, angular, fullpage.js

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 project that implements the fullpage.js port found here https://github.com/meiblorn/ngx-fullpage. I'm trying to implement scrolloverflow on one of my sections and I'm unsure of how to do it. I have included the necessary .js files in my `angular-cli.json` file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js",
    "../node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js",
    "../node_modules/fullpage.js/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"
  ],
```

Here is some html code where i'd like to have the second section be scrollable when there is enough content.

```
<div mnFullpage>
  <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
    <div class="fp-tableCell">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section welcome-section fp-section fp-table">
    <div class="fp-tableCell">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to check demo. How it works here 

https://github.com/meiblorn/ngx-fullpage/tree/master/sources/demo

Comment: Thanks for the link, I implemented it how it was in the demo now. However, would you happen to know how to update the scrollingoverflow on the page? Currently when it loads, it doesnt have enough content to go over the page, but after it sends some GET requests to a backend api server, it then does have to much content for the page but the scrolling doesnt update

Answer (score 0):

You can now change to the official Angular component for fullPage.js, which is maintained and always kept up to date with the new fullPage.js features and extensions.

- Repo: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage
- Demo page: https://alvarotrigo.com/angular-fullpage/